# How to remove duplicated items in iCarousel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview, icarousel

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/278

I am going to use the iCarousel to show the images linearly.
These images will be gotten dynamically.
Assume that there are 2 images.
But when I update iCarousel, there are also 2 images in background as following image.

[image]

While debugging code, I found that viewForItemAtIndex function is called 2 times after I called *reloadData* function.

*- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view*

[image]

[image]

So there are 4 images in iCarousel.

How to prevent to be called 2 times?

Please help me to fix this problem asap.

---

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImageView *puzzlePhoto = nil;
    UIImageView *puzzleBG = nil;
    UILabel *label = nil;

    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 112);
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        view.layer.doubleSided = NO;
        puzzlePhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46, 48, 40, 40)];

        //! get friend's photo
        FForesight *foresightCurrent = (carousel == self.icGameOnwhoAREus) ? [controller.gameManager.m_arrayStartedForesights objectAtIndex:index] : [controller.gameManager.m_arrayEndedForesights objectAtIndex:index];
        UIImage *imgPuzzle = [foresightCurrent getPuzzleImage];

        if (imgPuzzle)
            puzzlePhoto.image = imgPuzzle;
        else
            puzzlePhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puzzle background_small.png"];

        puzzleBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 112)];
        if (((foresightCurrent.m_intStage & FForesightStage_First) && !foresightCurrent.m_FCreatedByFriend) ||
            ((foresightCurrent.m_intStage & FForesightStage_Second) && foresightCurrent.m_FCreatedByFriend))
            puzzleBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"multi_game_one_item_bg_me.png"];
        else
            puzzleBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"multi_game_one_item_bg.png"];

        //! get friend name
        FUser *userFriend = foresightCurrent.m_userFriend;
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 32, 68, 16)];
        label.text = userFriend.m_strName;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:205.0f/256 green:55.0f/256 blue:2.0f/255 alpha:1];

        [view addSubview:puzzlePhoto];
        [view addSubview:puzzleBG];
        [view addSubview:label];
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I used iCarousel 1.6.3 beta.
So I have just upgraded with 1.7.2(latest version).
Though background images are removed, it doesn't scroll flexibly.
In another words, it hasn't inertia.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the code you are putting in your - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view method.

Comment: Though I put your sample code(in iCarousel-master.zip, iCarousel 1.7.2) into my project, it doesn't scroll flexibly, too

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly due to the views being recycled incorrectly. Views are re-used with different indexes, you you should never set index-specific properties in your view creation code. Here is the correct way to set up your item view:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImageView *puzzlePhoto = nil;
    UIImageView *puzzleBG = nil;
    UILabel *label = nil;

    const NSInteger puzzlePhotoTag = 1;
    const NSInteger puzzleBGTag = 2;
    const NSInteger labelTag = 3;

    if (view == nil)
    {
        //*************************************************
        //do setup that is the same for every item view here
        //*************************************************

        view = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 112);
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        view.layer.doubleSided = NO;

        puzzlePhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46, 48, 40, 40)];
        puzzlePhoto.tag = puzzlePhotoTag;
        [view addSubview:puzzlePhoto];

        puzzleBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 112)];
        puzzleBG.tag = puzzleBGTag;
        [view addSubview:puzzleBG];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 32, 68, 16)];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:205.0f/256 green:55.0f/256 blue:2.0f/255 alpha:1];
        label.tag = labelTag;
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    else
    {
        //get references to subviews
        puzzlePhoto = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:puzzlePhotoTag];
        puzzleBG = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:puzzleBGTag];
        label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:labelTag];
    }

    //*************************************************
    //do setup that is different depending on index here
    //*************************************************

    //! get friend's photo
    FForesight *foresightCurrent = (carousel == self.icGameOnwhoAREus) ? [controller.gameManager.m_arrayStartedForesights objectAtIndex:index] : [controller.gameManager.m_arrayEndedForesights objectAtIndex:index];
    UIImage *imgPuzzle = [foresightCurrent getPuzzleImage];

    if (imgPuzzle)
        puzzlePhoto.image = imgPuzzle;
    else
        puzzlePhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puzzle background_small.png"];

    if (((foresightCurrent.m_intStage & FForesightStage_First) && !foresightCurrent.m_FCreatedByFriend) || ((foresightCurrent.m_intStage & FForesightStage_Second) && foresightCurrent.m_FCreatedByFriend))
        puzzleBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"multi_game_one_item_bg_me.png"];
    else
        puzzleBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"multi_game_one_item_bg.png"];

    //! get friend name
    FUser *userFriend = foresightCurrent.m_userFriend;
    label.text = userFriend.m_strName;

    return view;
}
```

As for the scrolling inertia problem, if you're still seeing that after applying this fix, file a separate bug report on the github page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's same though I follow you.

Comment: If you carousel is not continuing to scroll when you release it, it may be something to do with the timer changes in 1.7.2. Try using 1.7.1 from the tags page on github and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: hey @NickLockwood , i have tried with this way but getting mismatching issue not getting exact views i am using  iCarouselTypeRotary with iCarouselOptionWrap == true .

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by performing reloadData on mainThread

```
[carousel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```